# Watch the monitor of a remote computer without being noticed

Tags: windows, monitoring, remote-access

Do you have any suggestions on a software that monitors the monitor of a remote PC without the user of the PC noticing? Don't ask me why we are monitoring or if it is legal. We have already been through that.

Comment: Many RAT (euphemistic acronym for remote administration tool) will do. I think the acronym says it all. Most serious/commercial administration tools insists on some kind of visual indicator, though. I personally like RADMIN. They offer a special installer providing the feature you ask for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Demanding that I not ask about the legality of actions you might perform with information I provide you doesn't exactly give me warm fuzzies...

Have your tried [VNC](http://tightvnc.com/) yet? You can disable remote input so it just shows what's on the screen.

Comment: Sorry about the legality sentance, the last question which was much of a duplicate did not get any answers to the actual question. Almost all the answers were alternatives which worked well for the OP's purposes. Just don't get carried away. We are in the US if you care to know.

Comment: I use tightvnc at home to monitor the "public" computer... Beats sitting next to whoever is doing whatever at the time.

Comment: Well, Chris S linked to TightVNC, which is why I commented under him lol. I'd say he deserves the credit proper.

Comment: @Aeo: O, sorry, I did not notice the similarity in name right off

Answer (score 1):

How smart's the user? :)

I know that with RealVNC you can hide the system tray icon. Perhaps if you run it as Administrator, and the user doesn't have admin privileges, they won't be able to see it in the taskmgr processes list.

There is a free edition available: www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[rautor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rautor/)?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to recommend it, but if you really, really need to do that, get a software like "Spectorsoft". It takes snapshots of the PC screen every X minutes. You can also google for "keylogger" or "spy software" to find tons of more software like this.

Answer (score 0):

TEMPEST would do the trick... how good are you with antenna?

Comment: Don't know what antenna is (except, Are you referring to physically hooking up to the monitor?)